# function descriptor on builtin types like dict.fromkeys behaves different to a normal method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals, python-descriptors

Why does the function descriptor for `dict.fromkeys` function differently then other normal functions.

First of all you can't access `__get__` like this: `dict.fromkeys.__get__` you have to get it from the `__dict__`. (`dict.__dict__['fromkeys'].__get__`)

And then it doesn't work like any other function because it will only let itself get bound to a `dict`.

This works fine what I expected:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 5

    def test(self):
        print self.v


class OtherThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 6

print Thing.test
Thing.test.__get__(OtherThing())
```

this however does something unexpected:

```
#unbound method fromkeys
func = dict.__dict__["fromkeys"]
```

but it's description differs from a normal unbound function to looks like: `<method 'fromkeys' of 'dict' objects>` instead of: `<unbound method dict.fromkeys>` which was what I

this works as expected:

```
func.__get__({})([1,2,3])
```

but you can't bind it to something else I understand It wouldn't work but that doesn't usually stop us:

```
func.__get__([])([1,2,3])
```

This fails with a type error from the function descriptor...:

```
descriptor 'fromkeys' for type 'dict' doesn't apply to type 'list'
```

Why does python differentiate builtin type functions and normal functions like this? And can we do this too? Can we make a function that will only be bound to the type it belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_or_type.descriptor` always calls `descriptor.__get__(None, class_or_type)`, which is why you can't get `__get__` from a *built-in* unbound method object. The (unbound) `method` type produced for `__get__` on a Python 2 function explicitly implements `__get__` because Python methods are much more flexible. So both `builtin.descriptor` and `class.descriptor` invoke `.__get__()`, but the object type that either returns differs, and for Python methods the object type proxies attribute access:

Accessing attributes via `__dict__`, on the other hand, *never* calls `__get__`, so `class_or_type.__dict__['fromkeys']` gives you the original descriptor object.

Under the hood, types like `dict`, including their methods, are implemented in C code, *not in Python code*, and C is much more picky about types. You can't ever use functions that are designed to work with the internal implementation details of a `dict` object with a list instead, so why bother?

That's really all there is to it; methods for built-in types are *not the same thing* as functions / methods implemented in Python, so while they *mostly* work the same, they can't work with dynamic types, and the implementation of how the descriptors work reflects that.

And because Python functions (wrapped in methods or not), could work with any Python type (if so designed), unbound `method` objects support `__get__` so that you can take any such object and stick it onto another class; by supporting `__get__` they support being re-bound to the new class.

If you want to achieve the same thing with Python types, you'll have to wrap the function objects in custom descriptors, then implement your own `__get__` behaviour to restrict what is acceptable.

---

Note that in Python 3, `function.__get__(None, classobject)` just returns the function object itself, not an unbound method object like Python 2 does. The whole unbound / bound method distinction, where unbound method objects restrict the type for the first argument when called, wasn't found to be all that useful so it was dropped.

Comment: So builtin-unbound-methods (if you can call them that) don't have a `__get__` and getting the unbound method from `__dict__` is a layer of `__get__` up?

Comment: If you were to implement a python interpreter, would you try to mimic this behaviour or would you rather have builtin stuff act the same as stuff you write in python. asking for a friend :P

Comment: @albertjan: but those objects *can't support binding to any other type*. They are much more picky as to what they need than a Python function ever is going to be.

Comment: @albertjan: that level of dynamism is just not worth supporting, so the Python interpreter doesn't.

Comment: @albertjan: and what would you imagine [the `dict.fromkeys()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/71f2dadf66c8f9f513bb67f3b06d320c406ac2ff/Objects/dictobject.c#L1415-L1509) would do when bound to a list instead? How would the C code I linked to even *work* in that case? It happens to already account for subclasses (that's what the `PyDict_CheckExact` calls are for), but making all C method implementations more flexible in the face of arbitrary types is a lot of work that is just not worth it for the very rare possible cases where you'd want to put the method on another class

Comment: It wouldn't work, but I would have expected it to fail when you call the function not when you `__get__` the bound version of the function. It doesn't make any sense to call this on anything else than a `dict`. I only chose `dict.fromkeys` as an example because that's what's used in the python2 test suite in `test_descr`. I was looking into the inner workings because I was working on implementing function descriptors in skulpt: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/pull/736 hence my question what would you do if you were to implement a python interpreter :)